# Hibernate test case failures

Tags: hibernate, github

While building hibernate version 5.2.8, I am facing some issues related to mockito exception. Similar failures are also observed on x86. Any idea where we can create issues for Hibernate(maybe on github or defect tracking system).

Details of the error log

> java.lang.IllegalStateException at ReflectHelperTest.java:51
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>               Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException
>                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate has a jira server, is that what you seek ?
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa